# should small videos be added to video-sitemap.xml

Tags: schema.org, video-sitemap

I have several professional videos listed on my site that I have included in both a video-sitemap.xml file and added schema.org/video JSON-LD to the individual pages. See [here](https://www.apis-iq.com/customers-section/videos/).
For my latest blog post though, I created two very quick 20-30 seconds, no sound or text videos that show on a loop: [here](https://www.apis-iq.com/2019/tips-tricks-user-meeting-2019/). 
My question: should they also be added to the video-sitemap? i.e. should any video, regardless of quality or length be added to the sitemap?

Comment: Do you want them indexed?

Comment: Yes. They are more "small snippets", than full videos. I just want to know what is best practice in this case.

Comment: I can't think of any good reason why you wouldn't want to add these "short" videos to your video sitemap, since they are part of your content and you do want them indexed. (?)